# how to fix compilation failure in maven 2

Tags: java, maven, maven-2

I am trying to build a maven projet on ubuntu but I got some compilation failure and this is the first time that I use Maven I can't undrestand what's the problem !!!!

```
  [DEBUG] Trace
  org.apache.maven.BuildFailureException: Compilation failure
at     org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:715)
at    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
at org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:516)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:114)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
```

Besides I got an error like missing symbol also

```
  [INFO] Compilation failure

   /home/user/oscars_dist1/oscars-0.6-sdk-01.11.11/eomplsPSS/src/main/java/net/es/oscars/pss/eompls/ios/IOSConfigGen.java:[15,28] cannot find symbol
  symbol  : class DeviceConfigGenerator
  location: package net.es.oscars.pss.api
```

Please help me any idea how to fix that !!!

thgis is the pom.xml file :

```
       <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
           <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
              <parent>
                 <artifactId>OSCARS</artifactId>
                 <groupId>net.es.oscars</groupId>
                 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
              </parent>

         <artifactId>eomplsPSS</artifactId>
             <name>Ethernet over MPLS PSS</name>
              <properties>
                   <spring.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
              </properties>
          <!-- puts all code & libraries in one jar -->
         <pluginRepositories>
              <pluginRepository>
                   <id>onejar-maven-plugin.googlecode.com</id>
                   <url>http://onejar-maven-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo</url>
            </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>



<dependencies>
    <!-- specific database -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.26</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- common SOAP interfaces (from local repository) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.es.oscars</groupId>
        <artifactId>common-soap</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- OSCARS utilities (from local repository) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.es.oscars</groupId>
        <artifactId>utils</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- OSCARS utilities (from local repository) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.es.oscars</groupId>
        <artifactId>pss</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- testing -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>5.8</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
    </dependency>

    <!-- database (from local repository) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.es.oscars</groupId>
        <artifactId>database</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--  issue 93 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xerces</groupId>
        <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- configuration -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jyaml</groupId>
        <artifactId>jyaml</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- database for unit tests -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- command-line parsing -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jopt-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>jopt-simple</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
        <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.16</version>
    </dependency>


     <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- CXF -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>

        <!-- puts all code & libraries in one jar -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.dstovall</groupId>
            <artifactId>onejar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <configuration>
                                             <mainClass>net.es.oscars.pss.eompls.common.Invoker</mainClass>
                        <classifier>onejar</classifier>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>one-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <!-- specifically use java 1.5 to compile -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>


    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[INFO] Compilation failure

   /home/user/oscars_dist1/oscars-0.6-sdk-01.11.11/eomplsPSS/src/main/java/net/es/oscars/pss/eompls/ios/IOSConfigGen.java:[15,28] cannot find symbol
  symbol  : class DeviceConfigGenerator
  location: package net.es.oscars.pss.api
```

That means that you have an error in  the class `IOSConfigGen.java` , i'm pretty sure that you have a missing jar so you have to identify it and search for it in the `Maven Repository` and add it in the `pom.xml` or if you didn'ty find him in `Maven Repository`, you have to DL him and install it manually .

Otherwise, you have to add it in your `Java Build Path`.

Hope that can help.

Comment: so after adding the missing jar files in pom.xml I should add them to my java build Path ?! because I already added some Jar to my pom.xml file and I still have the same problems and I am sure also it 's about some missing jar files

Comment: When you add them in your `pom.xml` and you execute `mvn clean install` you are sure you download them ? if no i think you have to configure proxy in `setting.xml` of your Maven, if you dowload them, it may be a problem with the jar so you have to download the specific jar and then install it manually with the command `mvn install:install -Dfile ...`